# opencv - face detection on android

Tags: android

Im trying to use face dection code of opencv on android
but there are some problems even i clean the project like the others said.

here is the description on the eclipse

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are
>   resolved  OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection        Unknown Java Problem
>   The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\OpenCV-2.4.3-android-sdk\sdk\java\bin\opencv library -
>   2.4.3.jar'    OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection        Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: Does the file `'C:\OpenCV-2.4.3-android-sdk\sdk\java\bin\opencv library - 2.4.3.jar'` exist on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly a problem with the path.

Have you checked the path correctly? (Jones suggestion should work for you)

If its correctly set... I would ask you to check the make file in JNI folder and use this full path, and also check the build path -> C++ -> GNU C++ -> add this path (if not already added).

Then you should be able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any .jar to import.

If you follow openCV tutorial (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)
 and import all Samples and Library you should be sure that Library project can be built without error.

In my case I have just set the Android Target at the current release 5.1.1.
To do that, right click on project "OpenCV Library - 2.4.11"->Properties->Android->Select Android 5.1.1->Apply